# How to enable auto upgrade as part of batch import

Tags: neo4j

I'm using batch import 2.0 script to do import of graph into neo4j 2.2. Every time after the import, if I try to start the server it fails with error message saying auto upgrade = true needs to be enabled in neo4j.propeties file. But since this file is not created after import but only after the first time I start the instance, I can't change it before hand. Any other way I can make auto upgrade step automatic instead of manual.? Why do I have to do this upgrade anyway? Is this a bug in batch importer which hasn't been updated yet to support 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch impoter ( https://github.com/jexp/batch-import ) has been updated to work with 2.2 some hours ago :), check the 2.2 branch.

Answer (score 1):

Batch importer is a part of the product in 2.2, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html.